# Joda-time, Period calculate issue?

Tags: java, kotlin, jodatime

the below codes returns same result, a 5 years difference.
should be 5Y, 5Y1D and 5Y2D?

```
val date1 = org.joda.time.LocalDate(2025,2,28) 
val date2 = org.joda.time.LocalDate(2019,11,28).plusMonths(3) 
val ddd = org.joda.time.Period(date2, date1)
println("${ddd.years} ${ddd.months} ${ddd.days}")

val date1 = org.joda.time.LocalDate(2025,2,28) 
val date2 = org.joda.time.LocalDate(2019,11,29).plusMonths(3) 
val ddd = org.joda.time.Period(date2, date1) 
println("${ddd.years} ${ddd.months} ${ddd.days}")

val date1 = org.joda.time.LocalDate(2025,2,28) 
val date2 = org.joda.time.LocalDate(2019,11,30).plusMonths(3) 
val ddd = org.joda.time.Period(date2, date1) 
println("${ddd.years} ${ddd.months} ${ddd.days}")
```

Comment: You can try to do the same thing using `java.time` and compare the results...

Comment: The problem with months is that their length is not fixed, and the exact period between two dates depend on your interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

No, it should not.

First, when adding three months to either 28, 29 or 30 November 2019, you are getting 28, 29 and 29(!) February 2020. 2020 is a leap year, so February has 29 days, not 30. Next, what is the period from 29 February 2020 to 28 February 2025? It’s not really well defined. You might argue that it is less than 5 years, perhaps 4 years 11 months 30 days? However, Joda-Time has chosen to regard it as 5 years since both dates are at the end of the month.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the use of `java.time` for more accurate results.

You can refactor your code to this:

```
fun main() {
    var javaDate1 = java.time.LocalDate.of(2025,2,28)
    var javaDate2 = java.time.LocalDate.of(2019,11,28).plusMonths(3)
    var jd = java.time.Period.between(javaDate2, javaDate1)
    println(
        "Between ${javaDate2} and ${javaDate1} are ${jd.years} years, ${jd.months} months and ${jd.days} days")

    javaDate1 = java.time.LocalDate.of(2025,2,28)
    javaDate2 = java.time.LocalDate.of(2019,11,29).plusMonths(3)
    jd = java.time.Period.between(javaDate2, javaDate1)
    println(
        "Between ${javaDate2} and ${javaDate1} are ${jd.years} years, ${jd.months} months and ${jd.days} days")

    javaDate1 = java.time.LocalDate.of(2025,2,28)
    javaDate2 = java.time.LocalDate.of(2019,11,30).plusMonths(3)
    jd = java.time.Period.between(javaDate2, javaDate1)
    println(
        "Between ${javaDate2} and ${javaDate1} are ${jd.years} years, ${jd.months} months and ${jd.days} days")
}
```

run it and get the following results:

```
Between 2020-02-28 and 2025-02-28 are 5 years, 0 months and 0 days
Between 2020-02-29 and 2025-02-28 are 4 years, 11 months and 30 days
Between 2020-02-29 and 2025-02-28 are 4 years, 11 months and 30 days
```